# Difference between Dictionary type and ABAP type?

Tags: abap, sap-data-dictionary

Sorry, I am new to SAP system, and I really can't understand some basic logic about the SAP system even I study and search in the Internet almost two days.
My question is: Why can I only use several Dictionary type in ABAP program? Below is my SAP system version:
[sap version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1YTDO.png)

For my understanding, `CURR` and `CUKY` these are predefined data types in ABAP Dictionary and we can use it in ABAP program because SAP system defined these types as default data element (is it correct?). ABAP program convert the predefined data types to ABAP types as follows:

[image: convert table]

In my case, I can't use the data type / data element of CURR/CUKY in the ABAP program but UNIT, DATS is ok.

[image: printscreen]

Am I missing some knowledge behind of it or misunderstanding something? Can someone explain clearly of that?

Thank you.

Comment: Please [DO NOT post images](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question.

Comment: This question has been answered in [SAP Community forum](https://answers.sap.com/questions/13036980/can-someone-clearly-explain-what-is-dictionary-typ.html).

Answer (score 1):

You are missing concept of domain types. You cannot use domain types directly in your ABAP code. CURR is domain not data element. You can use data elements and ABAP types in your code.

Data elements can be created by a reference to a domain or predefined types. Domains must be created from predefined types.